# What json.hpp to use for mac

Tags: c++, json, macos

I am working on a programming assignment, and it requires me to read a json file. To do so I am using https://github.com/nlohmann/json. When I #include "json.hpp" I get errors. I am guessing this is occurring because I need to encode it correctly for Mac. But I am not sure how to do so! Would anyone be able to help me with the same?

[Here is an image of my compiler ouput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWQRl.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That library is written in C++11 (as per the documentation).

Your compiler is not using C++11 by default.  To fix it will require something like this:

```
g++ -std=c++11 ...
```

If it complains that `-std=c++11` is not valid, try `-std=c++0x` (an obsolete synonym).

Comment: Thank you so so much!! :) This fixed it!